# How do I open properties box for individual services from command line or link?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, windows-search, windows-services

`services.msc` lists services. Can I open the properties box for them individually, **without** starting services.msc?

I would like a GUI control for windows search, but do not wish to keep the servcis.msc window open, I don't need the latter.

I would like to be able to open it either from command line (eg. as parameter to some program or dll?) or from a shortcut (eg. clsid?).

I'm on 7 but also have an xp box.

Comment: What version of windows are you on?

Comment: @EBGreen, windows 7, but wouldn't hurt if it would work in XP because I have an XP box too.

Comment: On your W7 box open a powershell prompt then type Get-Service. For the XP box install powershell then see the previous sentence. :)

Comment: @EBGreen Thanks! I think I can *control* the services from command line, with `sc` too, but I was looking for a GUI. I just don't know how to open the *gui* from the command line. :) I would like to keep the GUI open for my mental workflow.

Comment: Oh, I don't think there is a gui that would show you the info for just one service from the command line. You could write your easily enough in powershell though.